# Add element to struct

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I can't use ( push ) because it is used with state variable only

This is the error :

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6z1R.png)

Is there any alternatives for ( push )

```
  contract m{


  struct Message{

    address sender;
    address receiver;
    uint msgContent;

                } // end struct

 Message[] all; 

function get ( address from ) internal 
                                        returns ( Message[] subMsgs){


     for ( uint i=0; i<all.length ; i++)

      {
         if ( all[i].sender == from )
             { 
               subMsgs.push (all[i]);
             }
      }


          return subMsgs;  
          } 
       } // end contract
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `push` on dynamic-size arrays (i.e. storage arrays), and not fixed-size arrays (i.e. memory arrays) (see [Solidity array documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#arrays) for more info).

So to achieve what you want, you'll need to create a memory array with a desired size and assign each element one by one. Here is the example code:

```
contract m {

    struct Message{
        address sender;
        address receiver;   
        uint msgContent;            
    } // end struct

    Message[] all;

    function get(address from) internal returns (Message[]) {

        // Note: this might create an array that has more elements than needed
        // if you want to optimize this, you'll need to loop through the `all` array
        // to find out how many elements from the sender, and then construct the subMsg
        // with the correct size
        Message[] memory subMsgs = new Message[](all.length);
        uint count = 0;
        for (uint i=0; i<all.length ; i++)
        {
            if (all[i].sender == from)
            {
                subMsgs[count] = all[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return subMsgs; 
    }
} // end contract
```